# Scheffe’s Theorem

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I saw a statement of Scheffe’s Theorem as follows ([[1, p84]](http://www.ime.usp.br/~manuelg/arquivos/Probability%3a%20Theory%20and%20Examples%20-%20Durrett.pdf)):

> ... we need a simple result called Scheffe’s Theorem. Suppose we have probability densities $f_n$ , $1 \le n \le \infty$, and $f_n \to f_\infty$ pointwise as $n \to \infty$. Then for all Borel sets $B$
>   $$
> \left| \int_B f_n (x)dx - \int_B f_\infty(x) \, \mathrm dx~\right| \le
> \int_B |f_n(x) − f_\infty(x)| \, \mathrm dx
> =\int 2 (f_\infty(x) − f_n(x))^+ \, \mathrm dx \to 0
> $$
>   by the dominated convergence theorem, the equality following from the fact that the
>   $f_n ≥ 0$ and have integral $= 1$.

I feel that to use dominated convergence theorem, and to make the last equality work, we need one more condition that $\int f_\infty(x) \, \mathrm dx < \infty$. Or in this case actually this condition is not necessary?

Comment: It is assumed that $f_n$ is a probability density for $0 \leq n \leq \infty$, so he is assuming that $\int f_\infty = 1$ and yes, the condition that $\int f_\infty \neq \infty$ is necessary for the conclusion to hold in general.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian How do we get $\int f_\infty = 1$? Dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: He assumed that $f_n$ is a density for $n = \infty$ as well as $n < \infty$.  It's part of the definition of a density.

Comment: @ChrisJanjigian I see, it is $1 \le n \le \infty$. Thanks!

Comment: Also $\int f_n=1=\int f_{\infty}\implies \int f_n-f_{\infty}=0$ so by definition $\int (f_n-f_{\infty})^+-\int (f_n-f_{\infty})^-=0$ and on the other side $\int |f_n-f_{\infty}|=\int (f_n-f_{\infty})^++(f_n-f_{\infty})^-=2\int (f_n-f_{\infty})^+$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The condition that $\int f_\infty < \infty$ can be deduced from the other assumption. By assumption, we have $f_n \to f_\infty$ pointwise and each $f_n$ is a density. Hence $\int f_n = 1$ for all $n$. From Fatou's lemma it follows that
$$\int f_\infty = \int \liminf f_n \le \liminf \int f_n = 1.$$